# Retrieving firebase firestore documents in Flutter / Dart and Sound Null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working my way through a Udemy Flutter class and I am in a chapter dealing with Firebase.  The class is about 3-4 years old and it seems is just old enough that the sample completed code crashes when accessing the Firebase portions.  I started a new project from scratch and cobbled bits and pieces to get it mostly up and running but I have now hit a dead end.  The new project and the firebase plugins are Sound Null and the class code is not.  Getting and printing data from the database worked fine until I tried getting it hooked up to a stream.  I am specifically running into a problem iterating over the received documents.

When I set up the message variable using (the Flutter) `snapshot.data` in a for-in loop and try to iterate over the returned documents (#1) I have a null problem. Without specifying the type (#1a) as `AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>` the for-in loop errors that I cannot iterate over a non nullable.

Changing the type gets rid of the compile time error but generates a runtime error of

> Type _JsonQuerySnapshot is not a subtype of type Iterable

Dart is not my primary language and I have been pulling my hair out googling this for several hours to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance; //<-----earlier in the code

```
      children: <Widget>[

        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) { //<----Problem #1a here
            List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
            if (snapshot.hasData) {

              final messages = snapshot.data;

              for (var message in messages) { //<----------Problem #1 here
                final messageText = message.data['text'];
                final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
                final messageWidget =
                    Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
              }
            }
            return Column(
              children: messageWidgets,
            );
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after another hour or so of googling around I found the right place to look.  The docs for the flutter plugin for firestore have a massive difference from the course I am taking.  Reading(ctrl-c, ctrl-v) them I'm at least able to mostly understand and have the program back on track to finish my course.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).